# Jquery: Selection within a selection

Tags: jquery, selection

I have an array of different elements stored from a previous selection, call it '`a`'.

How do i then do another select from this previous selection (`a`) and just return elements of type `input`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
a.filter('input').each(function() {
    alert('My name is ' + $(this).attr('name'));
});
```

To just get a selection from the current selection this way:

```
var $inputs = a.filter('input');
```

You can even comma separate selectors:

```
var $els = a.filter('input, .fooMonger, #something');
```

See http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/filter

Answer (score 2):

```
$('input', a);
```

Comment: This searches input tags among the descendants of `a` and it works.

Comment: I think it's $('input', 'a');

Comment: No, it's not. `a` is a jQuery object as stated in the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(a).find("input")
```

Comment: If `a` comes from previous jQuery selection there is no need to wrap it around `$()`.

Comment: find will not work as it searches descendant elements, these are all level 1 elements.

Comment: I started answer with filter function, then edited and changed to find, because your question was not clear.