# how to select elements based on previous slector using jquery

Tags: jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Jquery: Selection within a selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1266604/jquery-selection-within-a-selection)

first I select div element from some page, code like this:

```
var divs = $('div');
```

how can I select those div with someClass from divs. I try to use

```
divs.find('.someClass') or divs.find('div.someClass')
```

both of them can't works.

what should I do if I want to achieve this task? By the way, I know I can use 
`$('div.someClass')`

Comment: Also please take the time to read the [API documentation](http://api.jquery.com/).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) method:

```
var someClassDivs = divs.filter('.someClass');
```

This will reduce the matched set of elements to those matching the selector (in other words, those elements with the "someClass" class name).

Your current attempt with `.find()` doesn't work because it looks at *descendant* elements. You are trying to reduce the matched set, which consists of (effectively) siblings.

Answer (score 0):

Use filer function

```
   var divs = $('div');
    divs.filter(function(){
    return $(this).hasClass("some_class");
                           })
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you don't use `$('div.someClass')` in the first place? Do you need an array of all divs for something else? First selecting all divs and then filtering the array uses more operations than simply using the classname as a selector, and will likely be slower.

My suggestion would be:

```
var divs = $('div.someClass')
```

Comment: yes, I am not just want to those div with someClass. I want the whole divs to do something else.

Comment: Ahh... Well in that case James Allardice's answer will suit your needs perfectly :)