# jQuery - Add nth-child to jQuery Object?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

is there a way to add the css selector "nth-child" to a jQuery Object?

E.g

```
var $myDiv = $('div');
$myDiv:nth-child('4n').css(); // yes I know this won't work...
```

Thanks!

Comment: Why can't you just do `"div:nth-child(4n)"` in the first place?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jquery: Selection within a selection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1266604/jquery-selection-within-a-selection) -- also have a look at http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the [nth-child()](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/) selector is supported.

If you already have a set of `<div>` elements, and want to obtain the ones that satisfy `:nth-child(4n)`, you can pass the selector to [filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/):

```
var divs = $("div");
var filteredDivs = divs.filter(":nth-child(4n)");
```

Comment: @Felix, true, a function is overkill here since `filter()` can also take a selector. Answer fixed, thanks :)