# Dynamically created elements - How to make proper selector and access top objects

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Jquery: Selection within a selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1266604/jquery-selection-within-a-selection)

Consider this code:

```
var $el = $('<div class="test"><div>Foor</div></div><div class="test"><div>Bar</div></div><div class="other">Leave it!</div>');

// won't work
$el.find('div.test').css('color','red');

$('body').append($el);
```

jsFiddle:

- http://jsfiddle.net/bVJkR/2/

How can I access `<div class="test">` elements using jQuery?

Please note I would like to access `.test` elements before using them in document.

I know I can create wrapper for divs, but I really would like to avoid it.

Comment: Try appending it to the body, THEN apply the css attributes.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/filter/ ... the jQuery docs are pretty good, going through it once saves you a lot of time later on.

Comment: @AustinBrunkhorst `Please note I would like to access .test elements before using them in document.`

Comment: @FelixKling That's it, thanks. I am familiar with `filter` method, but didn't though to use it! Thanks again

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your code `.test` is a root level element. Hence you should be using `.filter` not `.find`. `.find` is for descendants.

```
$el.filter('.test').css('color','red');
```